# Determinant of matrix product

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

The determinant of matrix product follows the following property unlike it's sum.
$$
    \det (AB) = \det A\det B
$$
Why is this true? What's the *easiest* proof?

Comment: Once you've studied elementary row operations, the easiest way is probably based on the effect of multiplying by corresponding elementary matrices on the determinant (of a square matrix).

Comment: 'unlike it's sum'?

Answer (score 8):

One definition of the determinant of an $n\times n$ matrix $M$ is that it is the *only* $n$-linear alternating form on $M_n(K)$ which takes the value $1$ on $I_n$.

Now the map  $\;\begin{aligned}[t]
M_n(K)&\longrightarrow K\\
M&\longmapsto\det(AM)\end{aligned}$ is an $n$-linear alternating form w.r.t. the columns of $M$. Thus it is equal to $\lambda \det M$ for some $\lambda$.  If you take $M=I_n$, you get
$$\det(AI_n)=\lambda \det I_n=\det A, \quad\text{so}\quad\det(AM)=\det A\cdot\det M.$$